# Does DBIx::Connector address the "per process basis" limitation of Apache::DBI?

Tags: database-connection, subprocess, mod-perl2, apache-dbi, dbix-connector

[Apache::DBI's docs](http://search.cpan.org/~phred/Apache-DBI-1.12/lib/Apache/DBI.pm) say:

> Apache::DBI [...] has a limitation: it keeps database connections
>   persistent on a per process basis.  [...In] a heavy loaded Web-site
>   where every user connects to the database with a unique userid[,
>   e]very server would create many database handles each of which
>   spawning a new backend process. In a short time this would kill the
>   web server.

[DBIx::Connector's docs](http://search.cpan.org/~dwheeler/DBIx-Connector-0.53/lib/DBIx/Connector.pm) do not mention this limitation, but does it still apply to DBIx::Connector, too, in a mod_perl2 context?